# what kind of video cable is this? please identify

Tags: video, cable

My video cable is busted, can some body tell me what kind of video cable is this? Please identify my video cable.

[image: (photo)]

Btw, my monitor is samsung synch master p2270.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) connector on one end, and some kind of [DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) on the other end – it would be DVI-A if it wasn't missing half of the pins.

Depending on what ports your monitor and your video card have, either VGA to VGA or DVI-I to DVI-I would work just as well, I think. (VGA is an analog connection, though, so DVI is recommended.)

Comment: Thank you grawity. ITs not missing any pins. The blue one is connected to the cpu which is the vga right? The other one with 9 pins goes to the monitor which i dont know what type is...

Comment: ...it's DVI like I said.

Comment: Thank you again for you help... I think i found the right one in ebay  http://m.ebay.com/itm/370967901600?nav=SEARCH&sbk=1   its dvi

Comment: 1a) Nitpick: "The blue one is connected to the cpu". Not quite. The CPU is just a very small chip inside your computer. 
1b) The cable does not care which side you connect where. If your computer and your monitor have the right plugs then you can even reverse it and it will work. 
2) According to the monitors manual (easily found on the web) it came with a DVI-A to D_SUB cable.  (DSUB, DB15 and VGA are different names used for the same connector).

[Screenshot of the manual page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2XaQk.png)

Comment: @Hennes, “CPU” is often used as term for the main system itself (i.e., everything in the case, not including monitors, keyboards, etc.) It’s not accurate, but it’s been used like that for a very long time. Also, [D-sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dsub) is actually just the style of connector itself and both the VGA *and DVI* connectors are D-subs. The manual should have said `DVI-A to VGA`, not `D-Sub`. To be honest, I’m really surprised by all the problems with it; I would expect better from Samsung.

Comment: `I think i found the right one in ebay ebay.com/itm/370967901600 its dvi` @KareenLagasca, that is only an adapter, not a cable. Technically it would be enough by itself, but it would be a real challenge to physically plug the monitor into the system with it because it is only ~5cm long. You’ll still need a cable.

Comment: Re CPU/computer: True. I know it is being used wrongly by a lot of people. That does not stop me from trying to correct it (even with a "nitpick" flag in front of it).

Answer (score 5):

## Identification

That appears to be some sort of non-standard DVI-to-VGA cable.

## Analysis

The blue end is a standard [VGA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector), but the other end is a [DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvi) shell with a non-standard [pinout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinout). Since the other end is VGA, then it is obviously meant to be using the DVI-A format (figure 1), but it is missing seven of the pins.

Six of those missing pins are not strictly necessary when using VGA, but your cable is also missing pin 16 which is used to let the system detect when you plug or unplug the monitor while the system is running. If you leave the monitor plugged in all the time, then this isn’t a problem, but if you switch it with a laptop or something, then the system will not be able to detect the monitor being plugged in or removed, so it would not be able to adapt and automatically start or stop using it. You should still be able to manually tell the drivers/software to scan for it, but that’s inconvenient.

## Replacement

When you look for a replacement, you can either use a VGA cable or a DVI cable, but you’ll need a VGA-DVI adapter dongle (figure 2). Make sure to get the right kind of dongle; check that the genders on the ends of the adapter match (are opposite of) the ends of the cable and the ports on the video-card and monitor.

If you use a DVI cable, make sure that is a DVI-*I* cable (it has the four single pins around the wide, flat pin), otherwise it won’t work with a VGA signal, even with an adapter.

## Recommendation

That said, your monitor definitely [supports a digital signal](http://www.samsung.com/my/consumer/pc-peripherals-printer/monitor/lcd-monitor/LS22EFHKFV/XM-spec), so assuming your video-adapter has a DVI connector (which it should if it was made in the last decade or so), you would be better off just getting a DVI cable and using it straight (no adapters, just DVI-to-DVI).

In that case, since your monitor’s maximum resolution is 1920×1080, you don’t have to worry about dual-link, so any DVI cable, other than DVI-A should suffice.

---

## Images

**Figure 1**: DVI connectors

[image: DVI connectors]

**Figure 2**: VGA-DVI adapter dongle

[image: VGA-DVI adapter dongle]